# How to horizontally center a bar plot annotation

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, plot-annotations

I am creating a bar chart like this:

```
gender = ['M', 'F']
numbers = [males,females]
bars = plt.bar(gender, numbers, width=0.1, bottom=None, align='center', data=None)
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    plt.annotate(str(numbers[i]), xy=(gender[i],numbers[i]))
plt.show()
```

I want to use `plt.annotate` to write the exact value on the top of the bar. However, the value is printed towards the right side. Is it possible to move it to the center?

[image: da]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- From `matplotlib 3.4.2`, use [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html).

  - See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for a thorough explanation and additional examples.

### Plot lists and annotate

```py
gender = ['M', 'F']
numbers = [1644, 1771]

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
p = plt.bar(gender, numbers, width=0.1, bottom=None, align='center', data=None)

plt.bar_label(p)
plt.show()
```

### Plot with pandas and annotate

- Convert the lists to a dataframe and plot with `pandas.DataFrame.plot`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': numbers, 'gender': gender})

ax = df.plot(x='gender', kind='bar', figsize=(12, 6), rot=0, legend=False, align='center', width=0.1)

ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])
plt.show()
```

---

### Original Answer

- In order to specify the horizontal alignment of the annotation, use the `ha` parameter

  - [matplotlib: Text Properties & Layout](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/tutorials/text/text_props.html#text-properties-and-layout)
  - [matplotlib: Annotations](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/tutorials/text/annotations.html)
  - [`matplotlib.pyplot.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html)
- As per the suggestion from [JohanC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12046409/johanc)

  - A trick is to use `f'{value}\n'` as a string and the unmodified `value` (or `numbers`) as y position, together with `va='center'`.
  - This also works with `plt.text`. Alternatively, `plt.annotation` accepts an offset in 'points' or in 'pixels'.

### Option 1

- From `lists` of values & categories

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gender = ['M', 'F']
numbers = [1644, 1771]

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
bars = plt.bar(gender, numbers, width=0.1, bottom=None, align='center', data=None)
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    plt.annotate(f'{numbers[i]}\n', xy=(gender[i], numbers[i]), ha='center', va='center')
```

### Option 2

- From a [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) to extract the `x` and `y` location needed for the annotations.

  - `x` being the categorical `'gender'` value
  - `y` being the numeric `'value'`

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1771, 1644], 'gender': ['F', 'M']})

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
bars = plt.bar(df.gender, df.value, width=0.1, bottom=None, align='center', data=None)
for idx, (value, gender) in df.iterrows():
    plt.annotate(f'{value}\n', xy=(gender, value), ha='center', va='center')
```

### Plot Output

[image]